# How to load/alter image tags from R?

Tags: r, image, machine-learning, dataset, exiftool

I want to add 'tags' to images by altering their metadata. I think I could use exiftool to start this process but am still unsure of how to go about this. For reference I have a .csv file with the tags I would like to add to images, the .csv file looks something like this:

| file | category |
| --- | --- |
| IMAG0001.JPG | Human |
| IMAG0002.JPG | Animal |

Now I would like to make it possible to load thing from the 'category' column onto images as metadata, preferably as 'tags' (such that you could see them in programs such as digikam). I'm not sure what the specific code for altering metadata.

I know that is is possible to alter metadata of an image using

```
exiftool("image.jpg", "Author=John Doe", "Comment=This is a comment")
```

but I don't know how to use do this in mass with many images at once.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main packages you can use `exifr` and `exiftoolr`. I'm going to use `exiftoolr`, because it uses system2(), which, unlike `system()` (used by `exifr`) is compatible with both Windows and Unix-based computers (e.g. Mac and Linux)

### Set-up

First, we install the packages, and get everything up and running:

```
# if either of these give you errors, install them with install.packages()
library(exiftoolr)
library(tidyverse)

# install exiftool
install_exiftool()
```

### Edit one image

I've downloaded [this photo from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Epepeotes_uncinatus_@_Kanjirappally.jpg):

[image]

Say we want to change the name of the artist (to play a prank on our friends).

To read the current exif data, we can exif_read() on the file, and we get back a dataframe, which we can select attributes from:

```
exif_read("/Users/pc/Downloads/Epepeotes_uncinatus_@_Kanjirappally.jpg") %>% select(Artist)
#       Artist
# 1 Praveen. P
```

Now, to change it, we run `exif_call`, with our argument(s):

```
exif_call(args = "-Artist=\"Mark Hill\"", path="/Users/pc/Downloads/Epepeotes_uncinatus_@_Kanjirappally.jpg")
[1] "    1 image files updated"
```

Now, when we run `exif_read()` again, the Artist attribute has changed:

```
exif_read("/Users/pc/Downloads/Epepeotes_uncinatus_@_Kanjirappally.jpg") %>% select(Artist)
#       Artist
#1 "Mark Hill"
```

### Edit many images

To do it many times, I'm going to assume all of the files are in the current working directory.

Loading your dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  file = c("IMAG0001.JPG", "IMAG0002.JPG"),
  category = c("Human", "Animal")
)
```

Then, it's simply a matter of looping through the files, applying the things you want to do:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  exif_call(path = image_file_paths[i], args = paste0("-XMP:Category=\"", df$category[i], "\""))
}
```

Comment: maybe I'm doing somthing wrong but it doesn't seem like 'exif_apply' is a real function, it just says: could not find function "exif_apply"

Comment: ah sorry I somehow didn't add that! Updated it to remove that. That was just a temporary function I had made while working on it